# How to add string to joomla header?

Tags: joomla

I know that with `JFactory::getDocument();` i can add some JS code to the header, but at the moment i need to add this kind of line `<!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->` Is there some default methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using Jdocument:

```
$document=JFactory::getDocument();
$customtag='<!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]--> ';
$document->addCustomTag( $customtag);
```