# How to insert custom html into Joomla header

Tags: joomla

I am using file_get_contents to acquire html. From the html page I extract the css, and js. Right now I am using a very expensive function.

```
 $css_elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('link');
    foreach ($css_elements as $css_element) {

        $Jdocument->addStyleSheet($css_element->getAttribute('href'));
    }
```

I would like to save the csss links to a file, and then read the file and add the links as a whole to the head tag of the HTML page.

I was wondering is Joomla has an in build function that allows for one to add unwrapped text to the head tag.

Thanx everyone!

Comment: have you looked at this? http://docs.joomla.org/API16:JFile

Comment: @Lodder that has nothing to do with my question. I want to add text to head tag of a joomla webpage. I need to know if joomla has a method that does this. Thanx for the try.

Comment: sorry I misread your question. well normally `$doc->addStyleSheet();` is used to add a custom css file and `$doc->addStyleDeclaration();` is used to add custom css. You seem to be using `$Jdocument` but do you see `$Jdocument = JFactory::getDocument();` anywhere?

Comment: I do have `$Jdocument = JFactory::getDocument();` . I am looking for a function in Joomla that would allow me to add custom text. For example, if I wanted to add `"Hello World!"` unwrapped to the head tag so that it looks like `<head> Hello World! </head>`.

Comment: What good would adding random text to the <head> tags do? For example, IF you did simply want to add Hello World!, what would be the point of it? The head is used to include scripts, add custom code, and for definitions, not random text.

Comment: I want to add 5 script and 4 css tags. I do not want to loop through as shown in the example above. I would like to add the css tags in one operation instead of 4 and the same goes for the js tags. I have looked through the Joomla documentation. It seems like they do not have the functionality I am looking for. Thanx for your help regardless. Oops, just looked at the side bar. There is such functionality.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909622/how-to-add-string-to-joomla-header?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Flexi Custom Code  module to do this in Joomla:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules/15251

*This module allows us to insert any code like php, javascript PHP, CSS and html at site modules positions. For example, It's can be used for simple code, simple function, embed code, adsense code, affiliation code and others copy and paste codes for Joomla site.
Main Features:
1. Available for PHP, HTML, JAVASCRIPT and CSS codes
2. Available to set the target of this module
3. Easy and flexible*